# Bug when using CharacterBuffers in android

Tags: java, android, nio

I am using a small compression library for short strings in java. Surprisingly when I run my application on my Nexus 7 (lollipop) it runs fine but when I run it on my ICS tab it give a noSuchMethod exception whenever I try calling CharBuffer.subSequence.

> 14016-14016/reach.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.CharBuffer.subSequence
>               at reach.project.utils.MiscUtils.compress(MiscUtils.java:239)

Error on this line :

```
String temp = String.valueOf(charBuffer.subSequence(0, 1));
```

I am using JDK 7

> ```
> compileOptions {
>     sourceCompatibility VERSION_1_7
>     targetCompatibility VERSION_1_7
> }
> ```

Min SDK version 14

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in the java compiler. Building with version 6 should resolve your problem.

According to [this](https://github.com/craigwblake/redline/issues/28) link and many others.

Comment: How can there be a bug in Java compiler :S well anyway, thanks, I'll try building with java 6

Comment: Yep, this works but this way you are creating another ```String``` object which may not be the needed behavior in some cases. Just wanted to mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

See detailed description of the phenomenon here: [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267495/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-java-nio-bytebuffer-flip)

Workaround for new compilers:

```java
package green_green_avk.anotherterm.utils;

import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.nio.CharBuffer;

public final class Compat {
    private Compat() {
    }

    @NonNull
    public static CharBuffer subSequence(@NonNull final CharBuffer that,
                                         final int start, final int end) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            return that.subSequence(start, end);
        return (CharBuffer) ((CharSequence) that).subSequence(start, end);
    }
}
```